# Querying Composite Key Sharded Mongo

Tags: mongodb, sharding, composite-key

I've created a composite shard key for a mongo collection:
{catalog_id:1,category_id:1}

Now if I query the collection just by catalog_id which is guaranteed to be unique, will the query go to all shards?

Comment: It may hit one shard or several. It that catalog_id is on all servers, then yes, all servers are likely to be queried.

Comment: in my case catalog_id is unique

Comment: Incidentally, if catalog_id is guaranteed to be unique, why are you creating a compound shard key?  Is it because you want an index on {catalog_id:1,category_id:1} anyway?

Answer (score 1):

In general, queries will go to whatever shards contain relevant chunk ranges for that query. In your case, if catalog_id is indeed guaranteed to be unique, then you won't have multiple chunks for the same catalog_id range (for instance, you won't have one chunk with range {catalog_id : 12, category : "a"} to {catalog_id : 12, category : "m"}, and another chunk with range {catalog_id : 12, category : "n"} to {catalog_id : 12, category : "z"}, because you can only have a single document with {catalog_id : 12}, and chunk ranges are created based on existing documents).

So in your case, the query should go to a single shard.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo db, If you have a compound index on multiple fields, you can use it to query on the beginning subset of fields. So if you have an index on

```
a,b,c
```

you can use it query on

```
a
a,b
a,b,c
```

Not sure if shardng works the same way.